# Using Google Wire with variadic function

Tags: go

I have a function that accepts variadic arguments, I normally uses it as the following

```
registry := repository.NewRepositoryRegistry(
    db,
    &repository.UserRepository{},
    // ...
)
```

Now, I want to use it with Google Wire

```
func initializeRepository(cfg *config.Config) (*repository.RepositoryRegistry, error) {
    wire.Build(
        repository.RepositoryRegistry
    )

    return nil, nil
}
```

But I receive the error

```
go run github.com/google/wire/cmd/wire ./internal/wire
cannot find package "." in:
        /opt/workspace/project/vendor/github.com/google/wire/cmd/wire
```

What can be?